# ionic 2 giving unexpected token when compiling simple project

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to implement a form in ionic 2 and am having a problem with the skeleton code I have written. When running ionic serve it throws the error `unexpected token` on line 8 of the following code in my form.js file:

```js
import {FormBuilder, Validators, formDirectives, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/common';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/photo/photo.html',
})
export class PhotoPage {

  constructor(form:FormBuilder){
    this.submitMediaItem = {};
    this.submitted = false;

    this.name = new Control('', Validators.required);
  }
```

Comment: This may not be your problem but there is a bracket missing from the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I had the same error previously. You can try this solution:

Check your version of ionic 2 using the command `ionic -v`. Mostly likely you are using the newer version of ionic 2 (mine is `2.0.0-beta.24`).

For the earlier beta version, it uses typescript so `form:FormBuilder` is valid typescript but not valid javascript. The newer version has moved on with babel JS so you will need to do as such:

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators, formDirectives, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/common';

@Page({  
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/photo/photo.html'
})

export class PhotoPage {
    static get parameters(){
        return [FormBuilder];
    }

    constructor(form){
        this.form = form; //or how ever you would like to use it
        this.submitMediaItem = {};
        this.submitted = false;

        this.name = new Control('', Validators.required);
    }
}
```

To return more than 1 parameters, you can do it as such:

```
return [[FormBuilder],[navController]];

constructor(form, nav){...}
```

There's a discussion thread regarding this error also: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-resolve-all-parameters-error/44969/7

Hope this helps!